# How to add Google repository from Command line SDK manager

Tags: android, firebase, android-support-library

I have tried updating android sdk using commandine

```
  ./sdkmanager "build-tools;25.0.3" 
  ./sdkmanager "platforms;android-25"
```

But the project still complains of `Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6.` and the reason for that is

```
// Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
// the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager`.
```

Can someone point me to the command of updating or fetching `Google repository` from command line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just solved it using command

```
 ./sdkmanager "extras;google;m2repository"
 ./sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository"
```

Upgraded to new version of repo

```
 ./sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-26"
```

List everything

```
 ./sdkmanager --list
```

Update All

```
 ./sdkmanager --update
```